# right bind when using align

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

I have multiple lines of equations in `align` environment, some of those are to long and I have to split them. How can I make the second line rightbound? What I do now is:

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper]{hepthesis}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
    a &= blabla
    a &= loooooooooooooooooooooooooooongexpression \notag \\
    & + \text{~~~~~~~~~~~} loooooooooooooooooooooooooooongexpression
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Which is of course quite ugly and in now way as it supposed to be done.

Comment: A dirty trick is to use `\hspace{1000pt}` and then check the size of the resulting overfull hbox in the log file. If it's overfull by n points, change 1000 to 1000 - n.

Comment: Probably the `multlined` environment of `mathtools` can help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no concept of “right bound”. You can use two strategies that differ for how the equation number is placed.

### `multlined` (from the `mathtools` package)

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper]{hepthesis}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  a &= blabla \\
  a &= \begin{multlined}[t]
       loooooooooooooooooooooooooooongexpression \\
       loooooooooooooooooooooooooooongexpression
       \end{multlined}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### `split` inside `align`

Note the `tbtags` option for `amsmath`. Without it, the number would be placed vertically centered with respect to the `split`.

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,tbtags]{hepthesis}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  a &= blabla \\
  \begin{split}
  a &= loooooooooooooooooooooooooooongexpression \\
    &\qquad\qquad loooooooooooooooooooooooooooongexpression
  \end{split}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In my view, the indentation should depend on the expression, if the break is at a non-fenced binary (like a `+`), then I don't think there should be any extra indentation (other than getting the `+` aligned on the right of the `=`.

Comment: @daleif I agree, but it depends on the expressions which we don't know the content of.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "right bind" the last part ot an equation, you'll have to play with `flalign` and the `\mathllap` (and incidentally `\mathrlap`) command defined by the `mathtools` package:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}

\begin{document}

    \begin{flalign}
 &  &     a &= blabla  &  & \mbox{\,}\\
  &  &    a &= loooooooooooooooooooooooooooongexpression   \notag \\[-4pt]
 &  &     & &&\mathllap{+ ~~~~~~~~~~~loooooooooooooooooooooooooooongexpression}
\end{flalign}

    \begin{flalign}
 &  &     a &= blabla  &  & \mbox{\,}\\
  &  &    a &= loooooooooooooooooooooooooooo\mathrlap{ngexpression}  &  & {\,}  \notag \\[-4pt]
 &  &     & &&\mathllap{+ ~~~~~~~~~~~loooooooooooooooooooooooooooongexpression}
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

[image]